# html5 : numeric input type

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, numeric

I've noticed something interesting in the ways FF and Chrome treat numeric input type. If I have a value of 12.23 Chrome complains about invalid input, but FF7 is fine with that. Chrome will only accept it if I change it to 12, or change the input type to text. Is that the 'normal' behavior of Chrome in regard to numeric input type? This occurs with the latest Chrome on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox hasn't yet implemented `number`, so it's reporting that it's fine because it's validating as a `text` field.

Chrome has implemented `number`, and the [default step](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#concept-input-step-default) for a `number` input is `1`, therefore [only whole numbers are valid](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#suffering-from-a-step-mismatch).  Your value isn't a whole number, so you need to explicitly set the `step`:

```
<input type="number" value="12.23" step="0.001">
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/HTAe5/).